# Deny to override fields of extended interfaces

Tags: java

For example I have the next interface:

```
public Interface A {
    String CONST = "someText";
}
```

I want to do something that can assemble interfaces like A. But I don't want that my assembler-interface could override members of its parent interfaces like:

```
public Interface Assembler {
    String CONST = "someText"; // there isn't any error
}
```

Can you suggest any solution?

Thanks!

EDIT: How can I deny to overlap fields from parent's interface? (When I use field in child-interface with the same name then the compiler shows to me some error)

Comment: Fields can only be hidden in the respective sub types but cannot be overridden (like methods, excluding static, private and final) because they cannot behave polymorphically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can never override fields, whether `static` (as in your case) or instance fields. All you can do is *shadow* them, but that's just a namespacing issue; all fields will be available, just possibly through explicit qualification by type name.

Whenever you need overriding, you need instance methods. In your case introduce a method that returns the proper string value. You won't be able to implement it in an interface, though.